# How to rename wordpress folders?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I want to change `wp-includes` to `includes`. I tried this in the .htaccess file, but I can still see `wp-includes` in the source.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_MOD_REWRITE:On]
RewriteRule ^includes/(.*) /wp-includes/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: "but I can still see `wp-includes` in the source" - You would need to actually change the URL in the HTML source. mod_rewrite is just a URL rewriting module... in your example it internally rewrites the URL from `includes/<something>` to `/wp-includes/<something>` (the underlying file-path).

Comment: This would probably get better answers if you asked it at [wordpress.se] instead of here.